# Iframe/href difficulties

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In short, we have a page with an iframe, and I want to target the page URL dynamically.

For simplicity, the page is located at http://1/2/3.aspx
The iframe would be on the 3.aspx page, and the iframe points to a completely different URL, let's say http://100/101/102.html

I want to target the iframe to go to http://1/2/"some URL"

A coworker suggested inline javascript using window.location.parent, but I can't figure out how to implement this. Using the usual ../ in the link's href tag only results in me navigate up within the frame's context (to 101, 100, so on).

As always, thank you to the community for your time.

EDIT: I would like to use inline javascript for this if at all possible.

Comment: You can't get/set `window.location` of a cross-domain page. Use `iframe`'s `src` property to change the location in `iframe`. Or is the link in `iframe`?

Comment: Hard to make much of sense out of this. Not clear at all whether you are trying to control the url from inside or outside the iframe or what would trigger changes. Also not clear if you control code in both iframe and page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this

```
<iframe id="ifr" src=""></iframe>
<script>
  document.getElemenById("ifr").src = "http://1.2.3/page.html";
</script>
```

*Update*

To use location data from the iframe's parent, you can do like this

```
<iframe id="ifr" src=""></iframe>
<script>
  var parenturl = parent.location.href;
  var newurl = parenturl.replace("from-this","to-this");
  document.getElemenById("ifr").src = newurl;
</script>
```

Comment: More or less, but the script needs to be in the iframe's content, and launched from there. The iframe is essentially getting the URL from it's parent window, and then getting the proper URL in relation to the parent window and loading in the parent window (the loading part can be taken care of with target=_parent, that I have.)

Comment: @Thomas Okay, so I updated how the script can access location data from its parent